# Уменьшение в размерах слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, css

Сделал слайдер, на кнопки перелистываются слайды. Но корректная работа слайдера зависит от ширины, потому что слайды мотаются лево-право. Нужно уменьшить ширину слайдера примерно наполовину.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="sidebar">
    <div style="background-color: red"></div>
    <div style="background-color: blue"></div>
    <div style="background-color: pink"></div>
    <div style="background-color: yellow"></div>
    <div style="background-color: green"></div>
    <div style="background-color: gray"></div>
    <div style="background-color: brown"></div>
    <div style="background-color: firebrick"></div>
</div>
<div class="navigation">
    <button class="left-button">
        Влево
    </button>
    <button class="right-button">
        Вправо
    </button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-bottom: 500px;
}

.sidebar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 200px;
}

.sidebar > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.navigation {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 5%;
}
```

**JS:**

```
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
const slidesAmount = sidebar.querySelectorAll('div').length
const leftBtn = document.querySelector('.left-button');
const rightBtn = document.querySelector('.right-button')
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

sidebar.style.width = `${(slidesAmount)*100}vw`
console.log(slidesAmount)
let activeSlideIndex = 0;

leftBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    activeSlideIndex--
    console.log(activeSlideIndex)
    if (activeSlideIndex < 0) activeSlideIndex = slidesAmount - 1;
    sidebar.style.transform = `translateX(${-container.clientWidth*activeSlideIndex}px`
})

rightBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    activeSlideIndex++
    console.log(activeSlideIndex)
    if (activeSlideIndex === slidesAmount) activeSlideIndex = 0;
    sidebar.style.transform = `translateX(${-container.clientWidth*activeSlideIndex}px`
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Может, стоит умножать слайдер на 50vw?
А вообще, если тебе нужен слайдер для рабочего проекта, то можно взять уже что-то готовое по типу slick-slider